# Renaming / Deleting worksheets based on contents of a range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I can work with spreadsheets but I have very little idea about coding, I've tried but I haven't been able to get anywhere.  I'm trying to do this for my school.

I have one page where I have the class list with an overview of the class grades and then I have another 26 tabs with a page for each student. I would like to create a button or an option in the menu that would help me rename the tabs (each sheet) with the name of the students... and if possible to remove those ones that haven't been used.

[image: student list] [image: tabs]

Comment: Code help service, not code writing service. I think you will want to create a menu function (so the script editor does not need to be opened to use your two functions). The function that does the deleting would need to read a range and then work with the `Spreadsheet#getSheets()` collection, to check the name of the sheet against the names provided. The function that does renaming would check a value on each sheet vs the provided names. Apps Script is JavaScript 1.6 with some [custom libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) for using Google stuff.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
function renameTabs(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Class List');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=sh.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    ss.insertSheet(vA[i][0]);
  }
}
```